# Oracle SQL Select on single table takes too long to execute

Tags: oracle11g

I have a select query that takes too long to execute(like 2 hours)

```
 SELECT mn_config_list_value.config_list_value_id FROM mn_config_list_value WHERE (mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 , :7 , :8 , :9 , :10 , :11 , :12 , :13 , :14 , :15 , :16 , :17 , :18 , :19 , :20 , :21 , :22 , :23 , :24 , :25 , :26 , :27 , :28 , :29 , :30 , :31 , :32 , :33 , :34 , :35 , :36 , :37 , :38 , :39 , :40 , :41 , :42 , :43 , :44 , :45 , :46 , :47 , :48 , :49 , :50 , :51 , :52 , :53 , :54 , :55 , :56 , :57 , :58 , :59 , :60 , :61 , :62 , :63 , :64 , :65 , :66 , :67 , :68 , :69 , :70 , :71 , :72 , :73 , :74 , :75 , :76 , :77 , :78 , :79 , :80 , :81 , :82 , :83 , :84 , :85 , :86 , :87 , :88 , :89 , :90 , :91 , :92 , :93 , :94 , :95 , :96 , :97 , :98 , :99 , :100 , :101 , :102 , :103 , :104 , :105 , :106 , :107 , :108 , :109 , :110 , :111 , :112 , :113 , :114 , :115 , :116 , :117 , :118 , :119 , :120 , :121 , :122 , :123 , :124 , :125 , :126 , :127 , :128 , :129 , :130 , :131 , :132 , :133 , :134 , :135 , :136 , :137 , :138 , :139 , :140 , :141 , :142 , :143 , :144 , :145 , :146 , :147 , :148 , :149 , :150 , :151 , :152 , :153 , :154 , :155 , :156 , :157 , :158 , :159 , :160 , :161 , :162 , :163 , :164 , :165 , :166 , :167 , :168 , :169 , :170 , :171 , :172 , :173 , :174 , :175 , :176 , :177 , :178 , :179 , :180 , :181 , :182 , :183 , :184 , :185 , :186 , :187 , :188 , :189 , :190 , :191 , :192 , :193 , :194 , :195 , :196 , :197 , :198 , :199 , :200 , :201 , :202 , :203 , :204 , :205 , :206 , :207 , :208 , :209 , :210 , :211 , :212 , :213 , :214 , :215 , :216 , :217 , :218 , :219 , :220 , :221 , :222 , :223 , :224 , :225 , :226 , :227 , :228 , :229 , :230 , :231 , :232 , :233 , :234 , :235 , :236 , :237 , :238 , :239 , :240 , :241 , :242 , :243 , :244 , :245 , :246 , :247 , :248 , :249 , :250 , :251 , :252 , :253 , :254 , :255 , :256 ) 
OR mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:257 , :258 , :259 , :260 , :261 , :262 , :263 , :264 , :265 , :266 , :267 , :268 , :269 , :270 , :271 , :272 , :273 , :274 , :275 , :276 , :277 , :278 , :279 , :280 , :281 , :282 , :283 , :284 , :285 , :286 , :287 , :288 , :289 , :290 , :291 , :292 , :293 , :294 , :295 , :296 , :297 , :298 , :299 , :300 , :301 , :302 , :303 , :304 , :305 , :306 , :307 , :308 , :309 , :310 , :311 , :312 , :313 , :314 , :315 , :316 , :317 , :318 , :319 , :320 , :321 , :322 , :323 , :324 , :325 , :326 , :327 , :328 , :329 , :330 , :331 , :332 , :333 , :334 , :335 , :336 , :337 , :338 , :339 , :340 , :341 , :342 , :343 , :344 , :345 , :346 , :347 , :348 , :349 , :350 , :351 , :352 , :353 , :354 , :355 , :356 , :357 , :358 , :359 , :360 , :361 , :362 , :363 , :364 , :365 , :366 , :367 , :368 , :369 , :370 , :371 , :372 , :373 , :374 , :375 , :376 , :377 , :378 , :379 , :380 , :381 , :382 , :383 , :384 , :385 , :386 , :387 , :388 , :389 , :390 , :391 , :392 , :393 , :394 , :395 , :396 , :397 , :398 , :399 , :400 , :401 , :402 , :403 , :404 , :405 , :406 , :407 , :408 , :409 , :410 , :411 , :412 , :413 , :414 , :415 , :416 , :417 , :418 , :419 , :420 , :421 , :422 , :423 , :424 , :425 , :426 , :427 , :428 , :429 , :430 , :431 , :432 , :433 , :434 , :435 , :436 , :437 , :438 , :439 , :440 , :441 , :442 , :443 , :444 , :445 , :446 , :447 , :448 , :449 , :450 , :451 , :452 , :453 , :454 , :455 , :456 , :457 , :458 , :459 , :460 , :461 , :462 , :463 , :464 , :465 , :466 , :467 , :468 , :469 , :470 , :471 , :472 , :473 , :474 , :475 , :476 , :477 , :478 , :479 , :480 , :481 , :482 , :483 , :484 , :485 , :486 , :487 , :488 , :489 , :490 , :491 , :492 , :493 , :494 , :495 , :496 , :497 , :498 , :499 , :500 , :501 , :502 , :503 , :504 , :505 , :506 , :507 , :508 , :509 , :510 , :511 , :512 ) 
OR mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:513 , :514 , :515 , :516 , :517 , :518 , :519 , :520 , :521 , :522 , :523 , :524 , :525 , :526 , :527 , :528 , :529 , :530 , :531 , :532 , :533 , :534 , :535 , :536 , :537 , :538 , :539 , :540 , :541 , :542 , :543 , :544 , :545 , :546 , :547 , :548 , :549 , :550 , :551 , :552 , :553 , :554 , :555 , :556 , :557 , :558 , :559 , :560 , :561 , :562 , :563 , :564 , :565 , :566 , :567 , :568 , :569 , :570 , :571 , :572 , :573 , :574 , :575 , :576 , :577 , :578 , :579 , :580 , :581 , :582 , :583 , :584 , :585 , :586 , :587 , :588 , :589 , :590 , :591 , :592 , :593 , :594 , :595 , :596 , :597 , :598 , :599 , :600 , :601 , :602 , :603 , :604 , :605 , :606 , :607 , :608 , :609 , :610 , :611 , :612 , :613 , :614 , :615 , :616 , :617 , :618 , :619 , :620 , :621 , :622 , :623 , :624 , :625 , :626 , :627 , :628 , :629 , :630 , :631 , :632 , :633 , :634 , :635 , :636 , :637 , :638 , :639 , :640 , :641 , :642 , :643 , :644 , :645 , :646 , :647 , :648 , :649 , :650 , :651 , :652 , :653 , :654 , :655 , :656 , :657 , :658 , :659 , :660 , :661 , :662 , :663 , :664 , :665 , :666 , :667 , :668 , :669 , :670 , :671 , :672 , :673 , :674 , :675 , :676 , :677 , :678 , :679 , :680 , :681 , :682 , :683 , :684 , :685 , :686 , :687 , :688 , :689 , :690 , :691 , :692 , :693 , :694 , :695 , :696 , :697 , :698 , :699 , :700 , :701 , :702 , :703 , :704 , :705 , :706 , :707 , :708 , :709 , :710 , :711 , :712 , :713 , :714 , :715 , :716 , :717 , :718 , :719 , :720 , :721 , :722 , :723 , :724 , :725 , :726 , :727 , :728 , :729 , :730 , :731 , :732 , :733 , :734 , :735 , :736 , :737 , :738 , :739 , :740 , :741 , :742 , :743 , :744 , :745 , :746 , :747 , :748 , :749 , :750 , :751 , :752 , :753 , :754 , :755 , :756 , :757 , :758 , :759 , :760 , :761 , :762 , :763 , :764 , :765 , :766 , :767 , :768 ) 
OR mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:769 , :770 , :771 , :772 , :773 , :774 , :775 , :776 , :777 , :778 , :779 , :780 , :781 , :782 , :783 , :784 , :785 , :786 , :787 , :788 , :789 , :790 , :791 , :792 , :793 , :794 , :795 , :796 , :797 , :798 , :799 , :800 , :801 , :802 , :803 , :804 , :805 , :806 , :807 , :808 , :809 , :810 , :811 , :812 , :813 , :814 , :815 , :816 , :817 , :818 , :819 , :820 , :821 , :822 , :823 , :824 , :825 , :826 , :827 , :828 , :829 , :830 , :831 , :832 , :833 , :834 , :835 , :836 , :837 , :838 , :839 , :840 , :841 , :842 , :843 , :844 , :845 , :846 , :847 , :848 , :849 , :850 , :851 , :852 , :853 , :854 , :855 , :856 , :857 , :858 , :859 , :860 , :861 , :862 , :863 , :864 , :865 , :866 , :867 , :868 , :869 , :870 , :871 , :872 , :873 , :874 , :875 , :876 , :877 , :878 , :879 , :880 , :881 , :882 , :883 , :884 , :885 , :886 , :887 , :888 , :889 , :890 , :891 , :892 , :893 , :894 , :895 , :896 , :897 , :898 , :899 , :900 , :901 , :902 , :903 , :904 , :905 , :906 , :907 , :908 , :909 , :910 , :911 , :912 , :913 , :914 , :915 , :916 , :917 , :918 , :919 , :920 , :921 , :922 , :923 , :924 , :925 , :926 , :927 , :928 , :929 , :930 , :931 , :932 , :933 , :934 , :935 , :936 , :937 , :938 , :939 , :940 , :941 , :942 , :943 , :944 , :945 , :946 , :947 , :948 , :949 , :950 , :951 , :952 , :953 , :954 , :955 , :956 , :957 , :958 , :959 , :960 , :961 , :962 , :963 , :964 , :965 , :966 , :967 , :968 , :969 , :970 , :971 , :972 , :973 , :974 , :975 , :976 , :977 , :978 , :979 , :980 , :981 , :982 , :983 , :984 , :985 , :986 , :987 , :988 , :989 , :990 , :991 , :992 , :993 , :994 , :995 , :996 , :997 , :998 , :999 , :1000 , :1001 , :1002 , :1003 , :1004 , :1005 , :1006 , :1007 , :1008 , :1009 , :1010 , :1011 , :1012 , :1013 , :1014 , :1015 , :1016 , :1017 , :1018 , :1019 , :1020 , :1021 , :1022 , :1023 , :1024 ) 
OR mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:1025 , :1026 , :1027 , :1028 , :1029 , :1030 , :1031 , :1032 , :1033 , :1034 , :1035 , :1036 , :1037 , :1038 , :1039 , :1040 , :1041 , :1042 , :1043 , :1044 , :1045 , :1046 , :1047 , :1048 , :1049 , :1050 , :1051 , :1052 , :1053 , :1054 , :1055 , :1056 , :1057 , :1058 , :1059 , :1060 , :1061 , :1062 , :1063 , :1064 , :1065 , :1066 , :1067 , :1068 , :1069 , :1070 , :1071 , :1072 , :1073 , :1074 , :1075 , :1076 , :1077 , :1078 , :1079 , :1080 , :1081 , :1082 , :1083 , :1084 , :1085 , :1086 , :1087 , :1088 , :1089 , :1090 , :1091 , :1092 , :1093 , :1094 , :1095 , :1096 , :1097 , :1098 , :1099 , :1100 , :1101 , :1102 , :1103 , :1104 , :1105 , :1106 , :1107 , :1108 , :1109 , :1110 , :1111 , :1112 , :1113 , :1114 , :1115 , :1116 , :1117 , :1118 , :1119 , :1120 , :1121 , :1122 , :1123 , :1124 , :1125 , :1126 , :1127 , :1128 , :1129 , :1130 , :1131 , :1132 , :1133 , :1134 , :1135 , :1136 , :1137 , :1138 , :1139 , :1140 , :1141 , :1142 , :1143 , :1144 , :1145 , :1146 , :1147 , :1148 , :1149 , :1150 , :1151 , :1152 , :1153 , :1154 , :1155 , :1156 , :1157 , :1158 , :1159 , :1160 , :1161 , :1162 , :1163 , :1164 , :1165 , :1166 , :1167 , :1168 , :1169 , :1170 , :1171 , :1172 , :1173 , :1174 , :1175 , :1176 , :1177 , :1178 , :1179 , :1180 , :1181 , :1182 , :1183 , :1184 , :1185 , :1186 , :1187 , :1188 , :1189 , :1190 , :1191 , :1192 , :1193 , :1194 , :1195 , :1196 , :1197 , :1198 , :1199 , :1200 , :1201 , :1202 , :1203 , :1204 , :1205 , :1206 , :1207 , :1208 , :1209 , :1210 , :1211 , :1212 , :1213 , :1214 , :1215 , :1216 , :1217 , :1218 , :1219 , :1220 , :1221 , :1222 , :1223 , :1224 , :1225 , :1226 , :1227 , :1228 , :1229 , :1230 , :1231 , :1232 , :1233 , :1234 , :1235 , :1236 , :1237 , :1238 , :1239 , :1240 , :1241 , :1242 , :1243 , :1244 , :1245 , :1246 , :1247 , :1248 , :1249 , :1250 , :1251 , :1252 , :1253 , :1254 , :1255 , :1256 , :1257 , :1258 , :1259 , :1260 , :1261 , :1262 , :1263 , :1264 , :1265 , :1266 , :1267 , :1268 , :1269 , :1270 , :1271 , :1272 , :1273 , :1274 , :1275 , :1276 , :1277 , :1278 , :1279 , :1280 ) 
OR mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:1281 , :1282 , :1283 , :1284 , :1285 , :1286 , :1287 , :1288 , :1289 , :1290 , :1291 , :1292 , :1293 , :1294 , :1295 , :1296 , :1297 , :1298 , :1299 , :1300 , :1301 , :1302 , :1303 , :1304 , :1305 , :1306 , :1307 , :1308 , :1309 , :1310 , :1311 , :1312 , :1313 , :1314 , :1315 , :1316 , :1317 , :1318 , :1319 , :1320 , :1321 , :1322 , :1323 , :1324 , :1325 , :1326 , :1327 , :1328 , :1329 , :1330 , :1331 , :1332 , :1333 , :1334 , :1335 , :1336 , :1337 , :1338 , :1339 , :1340 , :1341 , :1342 , :1343 , :1344 , :1345 , :1346 , :1347 , :1348 , :1349 , :1350 , :1351 , :1352 , :1353 , :1354 , :1355 , :1356 , :1357 , :1358 , :1359 , :1360 , :1361 , :1362 , :1363 , :1364 , :1365 , :1366 , :1367 , :1368 , :1369 , :1370 , :1371 , :1372 , :1373 , :1374 , :1375 , :1376 , :1377 , :1378 , :1379 , :1380 , :1381 , :1382 , :1383 , :1384 , :1385 , :1386 , :1387 , :1388 , :1389 , :1390 , :1391 , :1392 , :1393 , :1394 , :1395 , :1396 , :1397 , :1398 , :1399 , :1400 , :1401 , :1402 , :1403 , :1404 , :1405 , :1406 , :1407 , :1408 , :1409 , :1410 , :1411 , :1412 , :1413 , :1414 , :1415 , :1416 , :1417 , :1418 , :1419 , :1420 , :1421 , :1422 , :1423 , :1424 , :1425 , :1426 , :1427 , :1428 , :1429 , :1430 , :1431 , :1432 , :1433 , :1434 , :1435 , :1436 , :1437 , :1438 , :1439 , :1440 , :1441 , :1442 , :1443 , :1444 , :1445 , :1446 , :1447 , :1448 , :1449 , :1450 , :1451 , :1452 , :1453 , :1454 , :1455 , :1456 , :1457 , :1458 , :1459 , :1460 , :1461 , :1462 , :1463 , :1464 , :1465 , :1466 , :1467 , :1468 , :1469 , :1470 , :1471 , :1472 , :1473 , :1474 , :1475 , :1476 , :1477 , :1478 , :1479 , :1480 , :1481 , :1482 , :1483 , :1484 , :1485 , :1486 , :1487 , :1488 , :1489 , :1490 , :1491 , :1492 , :1493 , :1494 , :1495 , :1496 , :1497 , :1498 , :1499 , :1500 , :1501 , :1502 , :1503 , :1504 , :1505 , :1506 , :1507 , :1508 , :1509 , :1510 , :1511 , :1512 , :1513 , :1514 , :1515 , :1516 , :1517 , :1518 , :1519 , :1520 , :1521 , :1522 , :1523 , :1524 , :1525 , :1526 , :1527 , :1528 , :1529 , :1530 , :1531 , :1532 , :1533 , :1534 , :1535 , :1536 ) 
OR mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:1537 , :1538 , :1539 , :1540 , :1541 , :1542 , :1543 , :1544 , :1545 , :1546 , :1547 , :1548 , :1549 , :1550 , :1551 , :1552 , :1553 , :1554 , :1555 , :1556 , :1557 , :1558 , :1559 , :1560 , :1561 , :1562 , :1563 , :1564 , :1565 , :1566 , :1567 , :1568 , :1569 , :1570 , :1571 , :1572 , :1573 , :1574 , :1575 , :1576 , :1577 , :1578 , :1579 , :1580 , :1581 , :1582 , :1583 , :1584 , :1585 , :1586 , :1587 , :1588 , :1589 , :1590 , :1591 , :1592 , :1593 , :1594 , :1595 , :1596 , :1597 , :1598 , :1599 , :1600 , :1601 , :1602 , :1603 , :1604 , :1605 , :1606 , :1607 , :1608 , :1609 , :1610 , :1611 , :1612 , :1613 , :1614 , :1615 , :1616 , :1617 , :1618 , :1619 , :1620 , :1621 , :1622 , :1623 , :1624 , :1625 , :1626 , :1627 , :1628 , :1629 , :1630 , :1631 , :1632 , :1633 , :1634 , :1635 , :1636 , :1637 , :1638 , :1639 , :1640 , :1641 , :1642 , :1643 , :1644 , :1645 , :1646 , :1647 , :1648 , :1649 , :1650 , :1651 , :1652 , :1653 , :1654 , :1655 , :1656 , :1657 , :1658 , :1659 , :1660 , :1661 , :1662 , :1663 , :1664 , :1665 , :1666 , :1667 , :1668 , :1669 , :1670 , :1671 , :1672 , :1673 , :1674 , :1675 , :1676 , :1677 , :1678 , :1679 , :1680 , :1681 , :1682 , :1683 , :1684 , :1685 , :1686 , :1687 , :1688 , :1689 , :1690 , :1691 , :1692 , :1693 , :1694 , :1695 , :1696 , :1697 , :1698 , :1699 , :1700 , :1701 , :1702 , :1703 , :1704 , :1705 , :1706 , :1707 , :1708 , :1709 , :1710 , :1711 , :1712 , :1713 , :1714 , :1715 , :1716 , :1717 , :1718 , :1719 , :1720 , :1721 , :1722 , :1723 , :1724 , :1725 , :1726 , :1727 , :1728 , :1729 , :1730 , :1731 , :1732 , :1733 , :1734 , :1735 , :1736 , :1737 , :1738 , :1739 , :1740 , :1741 , :1742 , :1743 , :1744 , :1745 , :1746 , :1747 , :1748 , :1749 , :1750 , :1751 , :1752 , :1753 , :1754 , :1755 , :1756 , :1757 , :1758 , :1759 , :1760 , :1761 , :1762 , :1763 , :1764 , :1765 , :1766 , :1767 , :1768 , :1769 , :1770 , :1771 , :1772 , :1773 , :1774 , :1775 , :1776 , :1777 , :1778 , :1779 , :1780 , :1781 , :1782 , :1783 , :1784 , :1785 , :1786 , :1787 , :1788 , :1789 , :1790 , :1791 , :1792 ) 
OR mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:1793 , :1794 , :1795 , :1796 , :1797 , :1798 , :1799 , :1800 , :1801 , :1802 , :1803 , :1804 , :1805 , :1806 , :1807 , :1808 , :1809 , :1810 , :1811 , :1812 , :1813 , :1814 , :1815 , :1816 , :1817 , :1818 , :1819 , :1820 , :1821 , :1822 , :1823 , :1824 , :1825 , :1826 , :1827 , :1828 , :1829 , :1830 , :1831 , :1832 , :1833 , :1834 , :1835 , :1836 , :1837 , :1838 , :1839 , :1840 , :1841 , :1842 , :1843 , :1844 , :1845 , :1846 , :1847 , :1848 , :1849 , :1850 , :1851 , :1852 , :1853 , :1854 , :1855 , :1856 , :1857 , :1858 , :1859 , :1860 , :1861 , :1862 , :1863 , :1864 , :1865 , :1866 , :1867 , :1868 , :1869 , :1870 , :1871 , :1872 , :1873 , :1874 , :1875 , :1876 , :1877 , :1878 , :1879 , :1880 , :1881 , :1882 , :1883 , :1884 , :1885 , :1886 , :1887 , :1888 , :1889 , :1890 , :1891 , :1892 , :1893 , :1894 , :1895 , :1896 , :1897 , :1898 , :1899 , :1900 , :1901 , :1902 , :1903 , :1904 , :1905 , :1906 , :1907 , :1908 , :1909 , :1910 , :1911 , :1912 , :1913 , :1914 , :1915 , :1916 , :1917 , :1918 , :1919 , :1920 , :1921 , :1922 , :1923 , :1924 , :1925 , :1926 , :1927 , :1928 , :1929 , :1930 , :1931 , :1932 , :1933 , :1934 , :1935 , :1936 , :1937 , :1938 , :1939 , :1940 , :1941 , :1942 , :1943 , :1944 , :1945 , :1946 , :1947 , :1948 , :1949 , :1950 , :1951 , :1952 , :1953 , :1954 , :1955 , :1956 , :1957 , :1958 , :1959 , :1960 , :1961 , :1962 , :1963 , :1964 , :1965 , :1966 , :1967 , :1968 , :1969 , :1970 , :1971 , :1972 , :1973 , :1974 , :1975 , :1976 , :1977 , :1978 , :1979 , :1980 , :1981 , :1982 , :1983 , :1984 , :1985 , :1986 , :1987 , :1988 , :1989 , :1990 , :1991 , :1992 , :1993 , :1994 , :1995 , :1996 , :1997 , :1998 , :1999 , :2000 , :2001 , :2002 , :2003 , :2004 , :2005 , :2006 , :2007 , :2008 , :2009 , :2010 , :2011 , :2012 , :2013 , :2014 , :2015 , :2016 , :2017 , :2018 , :2019 , :2020 , :2021 , :2022 , :2023 , :2024 , :2025 , :2026 , :2027 , :2028 , :2029 , :2030 , :2031 , :2032 , :2033 , :2034 , :2035 , :2036 , :2037 , :2038 , :2039 , :2040 , :2041 , :2042 , :2043 , :2044 , :2045 , :2046 , :2047 , :2048 ) 
OR mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:2049 , :2050 , :2051 , :2052 , :2053 , :2054 , :2055 , :2056 , :2057 , :2058 , :2059 , :2060 , :2061 , :2062 , :2063 , :2064 , :2065 , :2066 , :2067 , :2068 , :2069 , :2070 , :2071 , :2072 , :2073 , :2074 , :2075 , :2076 , :2077 , :2078 , :2079 , :2080 , :2081 , :2082 , :2083 , :2084 , :2085 , :2086 , :2087 , :2088 , :2089 , :2090 , :2091 , :2092 , :2093 , :2094 , :2095 , :2096 , :2097 , :2098 , :2099 , :2100 , :2101 , :2102 , :2103 , :2104 , :2105 , :2106 , :2107 , :2108 , :2109 , :2110 , :2111 , :2112 , :2113 , :2114 , :2115 , :2116 , :2117 , :2118 , :2119 , :2120 , :2121 , :2122 , :2123 , :2124 , :2125 , :2126 , :2127 , :2128 , :2129 , :2130 , :2131 , :2132 , :2133 , :2134 , :2135 , :2136 , :2137 , :2138 , :2139 , :2140 , :2141 , :2142 , :2143 , :2144 , :2145 , :2146 , :2147 , :2148 , :2149 , :2150 , :2151 , :2152 , :2153 , :2154 , :2155 , :2156 , :2157 , :2158 , :2159 , :2160 , :2161 , :2162 , :2163 , :2164 , :2165 , :2166 , :2167 , :2168 , :2169 , :2170 , :2171 , :2172 , :2173 , :2174 , :2175 , :2176 , :2177 , :2178 , :2179 , :2180 , :2181 , :2182 , :2183 , :2184 , :2185 , :2186 , :2187 , :2188 , :2189 , :2190 , :2191 , :2192 , :2193 , :2194 , :2195 , :2196 , :2197 , :2198 , :2199 , :2200 , :2201 , :2202 , :2203 , :2204 , :2205 , :2206 , :2207 , :2208 , :2209 , :2210 , :2211 , :2212 , :2213 , :2214 , :2215 , :2216 , :2217 , :2218 , :2219 , :2220 , :2221 , :2222 , :2223 , :2224 , :2225 , :2226 , :2227 , :2228 , :2229 , :2230 , :2231 , :2232 , :2233 , :2234 , :2235 , :2236 , :2237 , :2238 , :2239 , :2240 , :2241 , :2242 , :2243 , :2244 , :2245 , :2246 , :2247 , :2248 , :2249 , :2250 , :2251 , :2252 , :2253 , :2254 , :2255 , :2256 , :2257 , :2258 , :2259 , :2260 , :2261 , :2262 , :2263 , :2264 , :2265 , :2266 , :2267 , :2268 , :2269 , :2270 , :2271 , :2272 , :2273 , :2274 , :2275 , :2276 , :2277 , :2278 , :2279 , :2280 , :2281 , :2282 , :2283 , :2284 , :2285 , :2286 , :2287 , :2288 , :2289 , :2290 , :2291 , :2292 , :2293 , :2294 , :2295 , :2296 , :2297 , :2298 , :2299 , :2300 , :2301 , :2302 , :2303 , :2304 ) 
OR mn_config_list_value.config_value_id IN (:2305 , :2306 , :2307 , :2308 , :2309 , :2310 , :2311 , :2312 , :2313 , :2314 , :2315 , :2316 , :2317 , :2318 , :2319 , :2320 , :2321 , :2322 , :2323 , :2324 , :2325 , :2326 , :2327 , :2328 , :2329 , :2330 , :2331 , :2332 , :2333 , :2334 , :2335 , :2336 , :2337 , :2338 , :2339 , :2340 , :2341 , :2342 , :2343 , :2344 , :2345 , :2346 , :2347 , :2348 , :2349 , :2350 , :2351 , :2352 , :2353 , :2354 , :2355 , :2356 , :2357 , :2358 , :2359 , :2360 , :2361 , :2362 , :2363 , :2364 , :2365 , :2366 , :2367 , :2368 , :2369 , :2370 , :2371 , :2372 , :2373 , :2374 , :2375 , :2376 , :2377 , :2378 , :2379 , :2380 , :2381 , :2382 , :2383 , :2384 , :2385 , :2386 , :2387 , :2388 , :2389 , :2390 , :2391 , :2392 , :2393 , :2394 , :2395 , :2396 , :2397 , :2398 , :2399 , :2400 , :2401 , :2402 , :2403 , :2404 , :2405 , :2406 , :2407 , :2408 , :2409 , :2410 , :2411 , :2412 , :2413 , :2414 , :2415 , :2416 , :2417 , :2418 , :2419 , :2420 , :2421 , :2422 , :2423 , :2424 , :2425 , :2426 , :2427 , :2428 , :2429 , :2430 , :2431 , :2432 , :2433 , :2434 , :2435 , :2436 , :2437 , :2438 , :2439 , :2440 , :2441 , :2442 , :2443 , :2444 , :2445 , :2446 , :2447 , :2448 , :2449 , :2450 , :2451 , :2452 , :2453 , :2454 , :2455 , :2456 , :2457 , :2458 , :2459 , :2460 , :2461 , :2462 , :2463 , :2464 , :2465 , :2466 , :2467 , :2468 , :2469 , :2470 , :2471 , :2472 , :2473 , :2474 , :2475 , :2476 , :2477 , :2478 , :2479 , :2480 , :2481 , :2482 , :2483 , :2484 , :2485 , :2486 , :2487 , :2488 , :2489 , :2490 , :2491 , :2492 , :2493 , :2494 , :2495 , :2496 , :2497 , :2498 , :2499 , :2500 , :2501 , :2502 , :2503 , :2504 , :2505 , :2506 , :2507 , :2508 , :2509 , :2510 , :2511 , :2512 , :2513 , :2514 , :2515 , :2516 , :2517 , :2518 , :2519 , :2520 , :2521 , :2522 , :2523 , :2524 , :2525 , :2526 , :2527 , :2528 , :2529 , :2530 , :2531 , :2532 , :2533 , :2534 , :2535 , :2536 , :2537 , :2538 , :2539 , :2540 , :2541 , :2542 , :2543 , :2544 , :2545 , :2546 , :2547 , :2548 , :2549 , :2550 , :2551 , :2552 , :2553 ))
```

Same query executes within minutes in one oracle server but takes too long on another server. The behaviour is consistent as it takes few mins to execute on server 1 but too long on server 2.
Oracle DB version: 11g

Can anyone please suggest possible reasons for this. Also, what all files should I be looking at to figure out the issue?

Comment: Formatted the query. Thanks for suggestion Tim.

Comment: Run EXPLAIN PLAN for this query on both servers and compare the output execution plan.

Comment: Constructing a SQL statement with thousands of bind variables in IN lists is probably not the best way to achieve your requirements.  You could instead put these values into a collection, or even a temporary table.